# Can't include the same interface with different parameters?

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following example:

```
public class Sandbox {
    public interface Listener<T extends JComponent> {
        public void onEvent(T event);
    }

    public interface AnotherInterface extends Listener<JPanel>, Listener<JLabel> {
    }
}
```

This fails with the following error

```
/media/PQ-WDFILES/programming/Sandbox/src/Sandbox.java:20: Sandbox.Listener cannot be inherited with different arguments: <javax.swing.JPanel> and <javax.swing.JLabel>
        public interface AnotherInterface extends Listener<JPanel>, Listener<JLabel> {
               ^
1 error
```

Why though? There is no overlap in the generated methods. As a matter of fact, that essentially means

```
public interface AnotherInterface {
    public void onEvent(JPanel event);
    public void onEvent(JLabel event);
}
```

No overlap there. So why is it failing?

---

In case your wondering what I'm doing and have a better solution: I have a bunch of Events and a Listener interface that's almost exactly like the `Listener` class above. I'm wanting to create an adapter and an adapter interface, and for that I need to extend all the Listener interfaces with a specific event. Is this possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. You cant.
It's because generics are supported only at compiler level. So you can't do thinks like

```
public interface AnotherInterface {
    public void onEvent(List<JPanel> event);
    public void onEvent(List<JLabel> event);
}
```

or implements interface with several parameters.

**upd**

I think workaround will be like this:

```
public class Sandbox {
//    ....
    public final class JPanelEventHandler implements Listener<JPanel> {
        AnotherInterface target;
        JPanelEventHandler(AnotherInterface target){this.target = target;}
        public final void onEvent(JPanel event){
             target.onEvent(event);
        }
    }
///same with JLabel
}
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot about type erasure. Do you know of an alternative way to accomplish what I'm wanting to do?

Comment: @Stas That seems like a ton of code per event (~50). Perhaps I should just go back to explicit creating a listeners per event?

Comment: @TheLQ, depends from your application. Usually, it can be anonymous class.

Comment: @Stas I'm having trouble thinking of how to integrate your class in my design. And I also found out that having 2 child interfaces that extend Listener and then implement both of them  doesn't work. I'm out of ideas here

Comment: @TheLQ, there was typo - JPanelEventHendler -> JPanelEventHandler in constructor.

Comment: @TheLQ, you need create instance of AnotherInterface as you want do it before. But when you will add listener you should wrap it, like `addListener(new JPanelEventHandler(yourInstance))`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that in java generics are implemented using type errasure, yet extension remains after compilation.

So what you are asking the compiler to do (after type erasure is),

```
public interface AnotherInterface extends Listener, Listener;
```

which you simply can't do generics or not.

Comment: I forgot about type erasure. Do you know of an alternative way to accomplish what I'm wanting to accomplish?

Comment: `class One implements Two, Three {

}

interface Other<T> {

}

interface Two extends Other<Object> {

}

interface Three extends Other<Object> {

}` - Change one `Object` to anything else and you get the error.  So, it's not because it's extending the interface in duplicate, and it does have to do specifically with Generics.